# Connection to the other side was lost - webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am tring to scrape all of the companies names from https://www.gpw.pl/spolki, futhermore I want to press "Pokaż więcej..." (in english show more) to scrape all of the companies names.

My initial code is:

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy.http.request import Request

from gpw_scraping.items import FinalItem

class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):
    name='GpwScraping'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.gpw.pl/spolki'
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//tbody[@id="search-result"]//tr'):

            item = FinalItem()
            item['name'] = row.xpath('//tbody[@id="search-result"]//tr/td/small/text()').extract_first()

            yield scrapy.Request( url=response.urljoin(profile_url), callback=self.parse_profile, meta={"item": item } )

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//html/body/section[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/a').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
           yield scrapy.Request( url=response.urljoin(next_page_url), callback=self.parse )


        yield item
```

However at the end I am left with the following error:

`[<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]`

If I want to have a csv with all of the names for all of the companies how can I achieve that?

What am I doing wrong I mean is this website simply blocking me from scraping?

**EDIT:** My best guess is that the website is blocking all web crawlers, I ve tried using different IP addresses and nothing has helped.

**BTW:** If you down-vote this question do not hesitate to write why :)

Comment: If you hit the remote server with a very high request rate, the script might be getting blocked as "no human could request that fast".  Consider adding a delay between requests.

Comment: Not the case I have this problem almost since the very beginning. I do not think that I was blocked due to the extremely high  request rate.

Comment: Try adding different user-agent

Comment: Same thing.....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the website can be blocking you.

Try to enable the [Autothrottle feature](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html) to avoid hitting the website too hard.

You can also try to set [user-agent](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent) to a [different value](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en). Eg.

```py
custom_settings = {
    'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
    }
}
```

If none of those helps you, consider using a proxy or VPN.

Comment: Hmmm.... my best guess is that the website blocks web scrapping. I ve tried from different IP adresses and nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Did you try using a different user-agent? I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, precisely the one you have given, still nothing :/